# Eventrigger routed event for AppBarButton?

Tags: xaml, windows-10

How would I make this storyboard go off on a click in the windows 10 uwp? My app just crashes on initialize component.

```
            <AppBarButton x:Name="nextButton" Label="next" Icon="Forward" Click="nextButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="messageTextBlock" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            To="0.0" From="1.0" Duration="0:0:01" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </AppBarButton.Triggers>
        </AppBarButton>
```